# How to get solid shadow of text in gimp?

Tags: gimp

I would like to take an object and give it a shadow similar to the one below (in gimp). How would I go about doing something like this (note, I'm not asking about how to make the object, I'm just wondering about the shadow)? Is there a specific tool, or a set of steps I need to follow?

[image: Shadowed text]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method:

- Use Layer/Text/Text to path to extract the path
- Duplicate the path
- Use the Move tool (in "Path" mode) to shift one of the two paths, so that one is the outline of the text on the top/front, and one the outline of the text of the bottom/back
- Use the **path-inbetweener** script from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/) to generate intermediate paths, about one or two pixels apart
- Set the brush to a small brush (1x1) and use the **stroke-visible-paths** script from the same place to stroke all the paths.

See examples [here](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=11318)